# Elasticsearch Data Streaming in python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I have the index in the Elasticsearch named livedata, which has the field datetime, item, price.
The data is ingested in the index every 10 seconds. I want the same data to be streamed in python from the Elasticsearch index.
Can anyone please help me with the python code for the same?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can use elasticsearch python sdk https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/current/index.html